# how to make a message that only displays after coming back from being inactive

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am working on a java program that basically simulates a bank account to make deposits, withdraws, display balance, etc. I have done almost everything. I am just stuck in one part to be finished. The program asks the user what is the starting balance and interest rate. The only thing I am missing is that I need to display a message that the account is inactive when the balance goes under $25, that is done. Now I need a message saying that the account is ACTIVE but only once the balance went down under 25 and then came back over 25. Every way that I have tried it shows the active every time the balance is more than 25, I just need it to display once after coming back from being inactive but can't manage a way how to do it. Any ideas would be appreciated, here is my code:

```
///BankDemo class
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankDemo {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unlikely-arg-type")
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        float startingBalance;
        float interestRate;
        String userInput;
                
        System.out.print("Enter beginning balance :$");
        startingBalance = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter interest rate(whole number) :%");
        interestRate = keyboard.nextFloat();
        
        float bal = startingBalance;
        float rate = interestRate;
        
        BankAccount ba = new BankAccount(startingBalance, interestRate);
        SavingsAccount sv = new SavingsAccount(bal, rate);
        
        while(startingBalance > -1) {
            System.out.println("Enter D for deposit" + "\nEnter W to Withdraw" + "\nEnter B for Balance" + 
                                "\nEnter M for Monthly Process" + "\nEnter E to Exit");
            userInput = keyboard.next().toLowerCase();
            
            if("d".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.deposit();
            } else if("w".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.withdraw();
            } else if("b".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.totalBalance();
            } else if("m".equals(userInput)) {
                ba.monthlyProcess();
            } else {
                System.out.print("Error, option not valid\n");
            }
        }
    }

}
///BankAccount class
 import java.util.Scanner;
public class BankAccount {
    protected float balance;
    protected float numDeposits;
    protected float numWithdrawals;
    protected float annualRate;
    protected float monthlyServCharg;
    float charge = 1;
    
    public BankAccount(float startingBalance, float interestRate) {
        balance = startingBalance;
        annualRate = interestRate /= 100.0;
    }
    public void deposit() {
        float valueD;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to deposit :$");
        valueD = keyboard.nextFloat();
        if(valueD < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance += valueD;
        numDeposits++;
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        float valueW;
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.print("Enter the amount you want to withdraw :$");
        valueW = keyboard.nextFloat();
        if(valueW < 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Must enter positive value\n");
        }
        balance -= valueW;
        numWithdrawals++;
        if(balance < 25) {
            System.out.print("Your balance is less than minimum balance. Your account is now INACTIVE\n");
        }
        if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
            balance --;
            System.out.print("You have exceeded monthly limit of withdrawals. Fee of $1 charged\n");
        }
    }
    public void totalBalance() {
        System.out.printf("Your Balance is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    public void calcInterest() {
        float monRate = annualRate / 12;
        float monInt = balance * monRate;
        balance += monInt;
    }
    public void monthlyProcess() {
        calcInterest();
        balance -= monthlyServCharg;
        numWithdrawals = 0;
        numDeposits = 0;
        monthlyServCharg = 0;
        System.out.printf("Your Balance after Monthly process is: %.2f\n", balance);
    }
    
    public void exit() {
        totalBalance();
        System.out.print("\nThank you. Bye");
    }
}
///SavingsAccount class
public class SavingsAccount extends BankAccount {
    private boolean active;
    
    public SavingsAccount(float bal, float rate) {
        super(bal, rate);
        if(bal < 25)
            active = false;
        else
            active = true;
    }
    public void withdraw() {
        if(active)
            super.withdraw();
    }
    public void deposit(float amount) {
        if(!active) {
            if(amount + balance < 25)
                return;
        }
        super.deposit();
    }
    public void withdrawals() {
        if(numWithdrawals > 4) {
            monthlyServCharg += numWithdrawals - 4;
        }
        if(balance < 25)
            active = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You show the messages only if the `active` status changes, i.e. when you deactivate the account:

```
if(balance < 25 && active) {
    System.out.print("Your balance is less than minimum balance. Your account is now INACTIVE\n"); 
    active = false;      
 }
```

And when you activate it again:

```
if( balance >= 25 && !active) {
    //print message here
    active = true;      
}
```

To achieve that in `BankAccount` it already needs the `active` flag that `SavingsAccount` has (the subclass wouldn't need it then). You probably also want to disallow withdrawals if the account isn't active.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was very helpful, it all works now.